# I Upgrade Flutter 1.22.4 to Flutter 2.0.1 but still I don't have web support on my pc

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutter-doctor, flutter-upgrade

I upgrade flutter to the latest version of Flutter stable channel which is also support web but not in my pc it doesn't show web and chrome see the image below.

[image: I upgrade flutter to the latest version of Flutter stable channel which is also support web but not in my pc it doesn't show web and chrome]

and please help me.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you performed the following steps:

- Enable web config: `flutter config --enable-web`
- Install latest stable Google Chrome (not Canary, not Chrome-like browsers)